# Can one install Windows SDK from NuGet?

Tags: winapi, nuget-package

Can one install Windows SDK from NuGet?

Is there some reason this has not already been done?

Comment: Please leave comments on why this would be undesirable rather than just downvoting. We have a variety of competing deployment mechanisms at our company for various types of machines. A nuget deployment would work across all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chocolatey seems to say yes to this:

choco install windows-sdk-8.1

Comment: It is perfectly possible to use the SDK without install or indeed without a choco install. Just a nuget package alone is fine.